# What is the point of [political-research]?

Tags: discussion, support, tags

There is a [political-research](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-research) tag, and it has no tag wiki or excerpt. I have done a cursory glance at the tag and its questions, but can’t seem to understand what it means.

What is the point of the [political-research](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-research) tag?

Answer (score 2):

Without closely looking at the questions in that tag, I'd say it's a synonym of [political-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-theory) which has the following excerpt:

> Political theory is the study of the concepts in politics. Use this tag for questions regarding political philosophy or scientific theories.

I think we should remove the [political-research](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-research) tag from those questions where [political-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-theory) does not fit. After that we can make [political-research](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-research) a synonym of [political-theory](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-theory).

Answer (score 1):

As for the [political-research](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/political-research) excerpt, I suggest,

> Political research is the branch of political science that investigates and analyzes activity connected to politics. Use this tag for questions about research into any aspect of politics. Consider [political-theory] if the question is not about research.

Responding to @JJJ's answer:

[What is the difference between Theory and Research?](https://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-theory-and-vs-research/)

> - Definition of Theory and Research:
> - - Theory is a generalized concept which provides an explanation to existing things.
> - - Research is a way of expanding the existing knowledge base and creating new knowledge.

While theory and research are related -- research leads to theory -- they are, or should be, distinct based on the content of the question.